# Leaflet - defining layer features for group of layers

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I would like to define the specified features for more than 1 layer.

I prepared the code like this, but unfortunately it dodn't work.

```
 var path = L.layerGroup([ecl, ant, hyb], {
  style: function (feature) {
  return {color: feature.properties.color};
  },
  coordsToLatLng: function (coords) {
  var latLng = L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(L.point(coords)); 
   return latLng;
  }
  }).bindPopup(function (layer) {
   return layer.feature.properties.descriptio;
  }).addTo(map);
```

I found a similar approach here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007088/leaflet-handling-a-geojson-composed-of-multiple-geojson

but it looks like I have to rewrite these properties for every single layer. I am going to have them at least a dozen or so.

The layers used in the code above are already under these links:

https://jsfiddle.net/ao07qjbh/

https://jsfiddle.net/xmdyqvr6/

https://jsfiddle.net/9sj25upo/

Is there any way to bunch them together and define one style?

Comment: What are `ecl`, `ant` and `hyb`? Without knowing your previous related question it would be just guessing what these might be. Please edit your question and add info about that.

Comment: the ecl, ant and hyb are geoJSON layers

Comment: But in your previous related question `ecl` was GeoJSON object. If `ecl` is really a Leaflet layer, then `coordsToLatLng` method should be use when creating it.

Comment: Can't it be applied to the layergroup I mentioned? (More than 1 layer?)

Comment: All relevant question info should be stated in the body of the question, not scattered in comments. Please edit your question and add info about nature of the `ecl`, `ant` and `hyb` objects.

Comment: Ok, will do it tomorrow. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starter, `ecl`, `ant` and `hyb` ar not layers, but GeoJSON objects.

Second, if you look in the Leaflet [docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layergroup) , `L.layerGroup` has no such options as `style` or `coordsToLatLng`.

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to use `L.geoJSON` method `addData` to add individual GeoJSON objects to GeoJSON layer:

```
var path = L.geoJSON([], {
  style: function (feature) {
    return {color: feature.properties.color};
  },
  coordsToLatLng: function (coords) {
    var latLng = L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(L.point(coords));
    return latLng;
  }
}).bindPopup(function (layer) {
  return layer.feature.properties.descriptio;
}).addTo(map);

path.addData(ecl);
path.addData(ant);
path.addData(hyb);
```